# cannot import name 'HTML' from 'html' . Python 3.7.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using Python 3.7.4
Simply trying to run this code:

```
from html import HTML
table_data = [
        ['Last name',   'First name',   'Age'],
        ['Smith',       'John',         30],
        ['Carpenter',   'Jack',         47],
        ['Johnson',     'Paul',         62],
    ]
htmlcode = HTML.table(table_data)
print (htmlcode)
```

But getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\UserName\Documents\Programming Learning\PythonLearning\Sending HTML Email\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    from html import HTML
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTML' from 'html' (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\html\__init__.py)
```

Is any other way to get HTML module?

Comment: Looks like you might be using this tutorial: https://www.decalage.info/python/html#attachments. Looks like there's a download link for a zipped .py file at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I did. But it still gives me an error

Comment: Put "html.py" in the same folder as your script. Then write `import HTML`, not `from html import HTML`. I think you want to import this downloaded file named `HTML`. The `html` module is a different module, which lives in the python standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try python 2.7

```
└─╼ python2.7
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May  1 2018, 18:37:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from html import HTML
>>> 
>>> quit()
```

python3 has html.entities.html5 and html._html5, neither of which may meet your objective